# I am not able to record place order activity and perform load testing on randomly generated URL

Tags: jmeter

at the time of recording activity I am recording complete activity till place order, but when run the same action for 5 times, in result everytime its hitting same URL that has been generated while recording, but because of it place order not recording to my admin account.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases unfortunately you will not be able to successfully replay the recorded script because modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for various reasons like [client side state tracking](https://meeraacademy.com/viewstate-example-in-asp-net/) or [security reasons](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#csrf-defense-recommendations-summary).

So you need to [parameterize and/or correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) your test and replace recorded hard-coded values with either dynamic parameters which needs to be extracted from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or provide [random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) values or use pre-defined values from i.e. [external CSV file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

The easiest way of detecting dynamic parameters is recording your test one more time and comparing 2 recorded script - the parameters which will differ will require your attention.

You can also consider using an alternative recording solution which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic values, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply.after debugging problem I realised that, every-time its trying to use same payment token for placing order when I run recorded script, but no Idea how to change it, so every-time response data showing payment declined, so not placing order,Any solution?? please reply.

Comment: @AbhijitBhagat only solution is that, start learning JMeter before doing any Performance Testing activities, this will help you a lot for this basic things. Also try working under a mentor. The solution is you need to do Parameterization and Correlation for dynamic values.